# Thunderbird Rendering UTF-8 Emails Incorrectly

Tags: windows, email, thunderbird, encoding

I imported all of my Outlook emails into Thunderbird. Since then, I've noticed that many of the emails render incorrectly - for example - `reason` appears as `reason�`.

Inspecting the source, these issues seem to happen due to UTF-8 encodings where hidden characters (such as `reason=85` - as opposed to just `reason`) were included when the email uses `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8`. I'm able to use [Charset Menu](https://addons.thunderbird.net/EN-us/thunderbird/addon/charset-menu/) to "repair" these emails, but it only works on an individual email, and doesn't re-save the email.

Is there a way to get Thunderbird to properly render all of these emails?

Comment: How are you importing the emails? I have used the add-on [ImportExportTools NG](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/importexporttools-ng/) with good results.